# Excel 2010 Moving Data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a table that I need to pull some data out and I'm not too sure on how to do this.

Here is an example of the table.

```
|   A    +   B    +       C       +   D   +   E    +   F    |
|--------+--------+---------------+-------+--------+--------|
| FNAME  | LNAME  | FULLNAME      | GRADE | EFFORT | CODE   |
|--------+--------+---------------+-------+--------+--------|
| FNAME1 | LNAME1 | FNAME1 LNAME1 | A     |        | GRADE  |
|--------+--------+---------------+-------+--------+--------|
| FNAME1 | LNAME1 | FNAME1 LNAME1 | H     |        | EFFORT |
|--------+--------+---------------+-------+--------+--------|
| FNAME2 | LNAME2 | FNAME2 LNAME2 | C     |        | GRADE  |
|--------+--------+---------------+-------+--------+--------|
```

What I need is to move the effort grade to the effort column, but in a different row.
Example Below.

```
|   A   +   B   +     C     +   D   +   E    +   F    |
|-------+-------+-----------+-------+--------+--------|
| FNAME | LNAME | FULLNAME  | GRADE | EFFORT | CODE   |
|-------+-------+-----------+-------+--------+--------|
| NAME1 | NAME1 | NAMENAME1 | A     |        | GRADE  | ←      To column E here         ←
|-------+-------+-----------+-------+--------+--------|                                 ↑
| NAME1 | NAME1 | NAMENAME1 | H     |        | EFFORT | → Move this Grade from column D ↑
|-------+-------+-----------+-------+--------+--------|
```

So an example of what I want...

```
|   A    +   B    +       C       +   D   +   E    +   F    |
|--------+--------+---------------+-------+--------+--------|
| FNAME  | LNAME  | FULLNAME      | GRADE | EFFORT | CODE   |
|--------+--------+---------------+-------+--------+--------|
| FNAME1 | LNAME1 | FNAME1 LNAME1 | A     | H      | GRADE  |
|--------+--------+---------------+-------+--------+--------|
| FNAME2 | LNAME2 | FNAME2 LNAME2 | C     |        | GRADE  |
|--------+--------+---------------+-------+--------+--------|
```

The kicker is, not all students have an effort grade, and if they don't have one there won't be a row for it.
Also, sometimes there will be an extra row with comments etc... so the data is not constant.

Comment: I believe you're looking for a pivot table. https://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/pivottables/2/

Comment: Please explain your situation more clearly.  Specifically, please show an example input and what output you want to get.

Comment: Sorry @Scott, I have added an example of the final result above.

Comment: Still kinda vague, but the pivot table seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a new sheet, copy the headers (`A1:F1`) and enter a 1 in a helper column. 
I’ll assume that you’re using Column `G`; i.e., cell `G1`. 
Enter

```
=IF(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, $G2)<>"", INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, $G2), "")
```

into `A2`, and drag/fill to the right, to `F2`. 
Then change `E2` to

```
=IF(INDEX(Sheet1!F:F, $G2+1)="EFFORT", INDEX(Sheet1!D:D, $G2+1), "")
```

and enter

```
=IF(INDEX(Sheet1!F:F, $G1+1)="GRADE", $G1+1, $G1+2)
```

into `G2`. 
Select `A2:G2` and drag/fill down as far as necessary.

Then hide Column `G`, if you want.

Column `G` is the index (on the new sheet) of the row on `Sheet1`
that we’re (primarily) drawing data from. 
It is one more than the index from the previous line
unless that points to row whose CODE is `GRADE`,
in which case we assume that it’s an `EFFORT` row
and add two to the previous (i.e., to skip over the `EFFORT` row). 
Columns `A`-`D` and `F` are simply copied from the same column on `Sheet1`,
as indexed by Column `G`.
The formula in Column `E` (EFFORT) looks to see
whether the current student is one with two rows
(so `$G2+1` refers to the same student, with a CODE of `EFFORT`)
and, if so, pulls the EFFORT grade from Column `D` of that second row.

For these data:

```
+   A   +   B    +      C       +   D   +   E    +   F    +
+-------+--------+--------------+-------+--------+--------+
| FNAME | LNAME  |   FULLNAME   | GRADE | EFFORT |  CODE  |
+-------+--------+--------------+-------+--------+--------+
| John  | Smith  | John Smith   | A     |        | GRADE  |
| John  | Smith  | John Smith   | H     |        | EFFORT |
| Mary  | Jones  | Mary Jones   | B     |        | GRADE  |
| Isaac | Newton | Isaac Newton | A+    |        | GRADE  |
| Isaac | Newton | Isaac Newton | C     |        | EFFORT |
+-------+--------+--------------+-------+--------+--------+
```

I got this result:

[image: spreadsheet]

Answer (score 0):

You can handle that without pivot.

Based on your example, put this on your `Effort` column on `Sheet2`:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$10, MATCH(1, (Sheet2!$C2 = Sheet1!$C$2:$C$10) * (Sheet1!$F$2:$F$10 = "EFFORT"), 0))
```

and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert the array formula.

### Explanation

`Sheet1!$D$2:$D$10` is your `Effort` column on your source table on Sheet1.

`(Sheet2!$C2 = Sheet1!$C$2:$C$10)` is looking up the matching `FULLNAME`

`(Sheet1!$F$2:$F$10 = "EFFORT")` is looking up the matching `CODE`, which is "EFFORT"

Both return boolean value, `0` and `1`. If both conditions match (found a row with matching FULLNAME and CODE), then it returns 1 ( `1 * 1` ) to the `MATCH` function.